# Why is the German word for "cartridge" "die Patrone"?

Tags: etymology

In many other languages the name referring to a firearm cartridge derives distantly from the Latin `carta`, `cartae`

- meaning paper, because of how 16th century firearm charges were wrapped.

In German the same concept comes probably from the Latin `patronus`, `patroni`

- meaning defender, protector; itself derived from the Latin from `pater`, `patris`.

Why does the German word for cartridge come from `patronus`?

Comment: Because I am no export in ammunition I can not answer the question: But there is the German word Kartusche https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartusche_(Munition)

Comment: @IngoBochmann thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @ShegitBrahm is there an official formatting policy on GeSE? Is it not a bit ugly to format Latin words as it has been done in the edit? And why was _patronus_ at the end not formatted like the other ones? I'm asking just to know how to format in future questions.

Comment: @Easymode44: the only "official formatting policy" I would claim is: make the text clearly and easily readable. So yes, you are free to change my formatting. My aim was to highlight the non-english words and I oversaw the last word.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Fair point, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cartridge (in German "**Patrone**" from French Patron for form, pattern, model) combines the components necessary to fire a bullet (projectile or grenade) from a firearm into one unit. The unit cartridge (in German "**Einheitspatrone**") usually consists of a case, primer, propellant charge and projectile. Historical cartridges do not make this unit.

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Patrone&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPatrone%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CPatrone%3B%2Cc0)

Further information:

> Patrone is a form of the masculine Patron (form, pattern, model)
>   existing since the 17th century. It was taken from the French
>   `patron`, which in turn was borrowed from the Latin `patronus`. In
>   addition to the Latin and Middle Latin meanings of 'patron saint' and
>   'patron saint', the French word already had the meanings 'model' and
>   'pattern' at the time of Old French, which were later also found in
>   Middle Latin.
>
> They developed out of a metaphorical use of the word patron, because the
>   pattern form is the father form, on which the emergence of something
>   else is modelled and the father is the model of the son. Patron
>   found its way into the German dialects and various technical
>   languages, so that at the end of the 16th century the word, in the meaning
>   'Musterform', also referred to the quantity of gunpowder required for a
>   charge in a case first made from paper, then from metal, before it subsequently
>   stood for the entire charge prepared in this way.
>
> The term was then also applied to modern projectiles, which had a
>   case, a propellant charge and an igniter. The external resemblance to
>   these is ultimately what caused the designation of containers for 35mm
>   films and ink for fountain pens as Patrone, which emerged in the
>   20th century.

German source: [Wiktionary - Patrone](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Patrone)

> Patrone ist eine seit dem 17. Jahrhundert existierende Form des
>   Maskulinums Patron (Form, Muster, Modell). Dieses wurde vom
>   französischen `patron` übernommen, welches seinerseits aus dem
>   lateinischen `patronus` entlehnt wurde. Das französische Wort wies
>   außer den aus dem Lateinischen und Mittellateinischen stammenden
>   Bedeutungen ‚Schutzherr‘ und ‚Schutzheiliger‘ schon zur Zeit des
>   Altfranzösischen die Bedeutungen ‚Modell‘ und ‚Muster‘ auf, die sich
>   später auch im Mittellateinischen fanden.
>
> Sie entwickelten sich aus einem bildlichen Gebrauch des Wortes
>   Schutzherr heraus, weil die Musterform die Vaterform ist, an der sich
>   die Entstehung von etwas anderem orientiert und der Vater das Vorbild
>   des Sohnes ist. Patron fand im Deutschen Eingang in die Mundarten und
>   diverse Fachsprachen, so dass das Wort in der Bedeutung ‚Musterform‘
>   am Ende des 16. Jahrhunderts auch die für eine Ladung benötigte Menge
>   Schießpulvers in einer zuerst papiernen, später metallenen Hülse
>   bezeichnete, bevor es in der Folge für die ganze so vorbereitete
>   Ladung stand.
>
> Sodann wurde der Begriff ebenfalls auf die modernen Geschosse, die
>   über Hülse, Treibladung und Zünder verfügen, übertragen. Der äußeren
>   Ähnlichkeit mit diesen ist schlussendlich die Bezeichnung von
>   Behältnissen für Kleinbildfilme und Tinte für Füller als Patrone
>   geschuldet, die im 20. Jahrhundert aufkam.

Comment: There is a quote markup for quotes, please use it in the future

Comment: Since the question was asked in English you should provide a translation of the quote.

Comment: @infinitezero - added translation draft.

Comment: Thank you @help-info.de for your thorough answer. Very interesting.